# Using awk to print an 'nth' number of fields inside a for i loop

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have written a one liner that searches a file that is a list of strings against some files in a folder.

The idea is to create a new output that lists the string that was searched, followed by all of the files it found it in.

The file *list* contains the following

```
alexl-lap:projects alexl$ cat list
abc-123
def-456
```

This is what I have so far:

```
alexl-lap:projects alexl$ for i in `cat list` ; do printf "\n$i:\n" ;  grep -l --color=always $i * | /usr/bin/awk '{printf("%s\n", $0)}' ; done >> log.txt

alexl-lap:projects alexl$ cat log.txt

abc-123:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

def-456:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
```

If I now run the following command, this is what I get

```
alexl-lap:projects alexl$ /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"} {print $1 " " $2 "" $3 "" $4 "" $5 " "}' < log.txt
abc-123: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
def-456: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
```

This use of manually specifying the fields is clearly bad practice. If a string being searched was found in 15 files, I would need to include 1-15.

How can I achieve this using an 'nth' variable?

I would like the same output but where awk looks at the number of files that the file was found in, and prints all of those out after the string it searched (in one line).

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, there seem to be a lot of unnecessary steps taken here - could you [edit] your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do, showing us a sample of input and output?

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that all `file*txt` filenames do not contain special char nor `:`.

Give it a try:

```
grep -Hf list *txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {string=substr($0,length($1)+2); if (!filenames[string]) {filenames[string]=$1;} else {filenames[string]=sprintf("%s %s",filenames[string],$1);}} END {for (string in filenames) { print string ":" filenames[string]; }}'

def-456:file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
abc-123:file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```